# Nodemailer error: socket hang up

Tags: javascript, node.js, smtp, nodemailer

I am trying to send an email using nodemailer through our smtp server, but I'm getting this error:

```
{ Error: socket hang up
at TLSSocket.onHangUp (_tls_wrap.js:1117:19)
at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:290:19)
at emitNone (events.js:91:20)
at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:185:7)
at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:974:12)
at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:74:11)
at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:98:9) code: 'ECONNECTION', command: 'CONN' }
```

The code is the following:

```
let transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
    host: "<corporative host>",
    port: 465,
    debug: true,
    secure: true,
    auth: {
      user: "<my_user>",
      pass: "<my password>"
    }
});

let mailOptions = {
    from: "myuser@host", // sender address
    to: "test@test.org", // list of receivers
    subject: "Hello ✔", // Subject line
    text: "Hello world ?", // plain text body
    html: "<b>Hello world ?</b>" // html body
};


transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, (error, info) => {
    console.log("SENDING");
    if (error) {
         return console.log(error);
    }
    console.log("Message %s sent: %s", info.messageId, info.response);
});
```

Could someone explain me where does this error come from and how to fix it?

Comment: Try using telnet to check if your mail server really listens to <corporative host>:465

Comment: It does. In fact I c&p my thunderbird smtp config.

Comment: when I am sending 10 mail using for loop, it works fine. But when I am trying to send 100 mails it gives the same error as stated in above question